# Lost all my baby photos when oldest son turned off family sharing, please help!

Tags: icloud, photos, family-sharing

My account is the master for family sharing. I’m missing important photos and want to find them of possible.

My son has turned off family sharing on his ipad air 1 approx few months ago. I only discovered yesterday that the photos were gone but my son says he did turn off a couple of months ago. There are no photos on my sons ipad  now - He says he deleted them.

The photos in question were taken with my iphone but they have vanished and I was updating to the icloud but they dont appear to be in there either.

Basically all of my photos have disappeared from my iphone 4 and the icloud. Is there anyway to get these back?

Answer (score 1):

I'll provide the best answer I can for now, as time may be of the essence here, but I would suggest that you provide your iPadOS version here also in case there are any differences between how it currently works and any older version you may be running. That being said:

1. Open the Photos app.
2. Tap "Albums".
3. Tap "Recently Deleted".
4. Tap "Select".
5. Tap "Recover All".
6. Tap "Recover [number] Items" to confirm.

Anything that was deleted within the last month should still be in there. If it's been longer than a month, you may be out of luck, unfortunately, but I would still encourage you to reach out to Apple Support in case there's anything at all they can do to help you, as it sounds like these are very important photos to you. If Apple Support also cannot help, there is software such as Disk Drill or other utilities you can try for recovering this data. Often these utilities come with a free trial period so you may not have to pay anything if you decide not to keep the software. There are also totally free recovery utilities but they may not be as user-friendly. Good luck!

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205856

https://www.cleverfiles.com

Comment: Judging by the date on the question, it's been longer than a month.

Comment: Oh, goodness -- I hadn't noticed that! I hope everything worked out OK for OP. I'm confused as to why this question was kicked up to me when I came to the Ask Different page...maybe I don't understand how this works.

Comment: There's been some spam posts. Questions with no answers are also 'bounced' occasionally. It's a good answer, and may help someone else with the same problem.

Comment: Ah, OK -- thanks for the clarification on that -- I was confused for a minute; I'll have to pay closer attention to the timestamp in the future. Yeah, I hope it can help someone; I know I'd be pretty devastated if I lost my family photos.